# How to resolve the @NgModule issue in the angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

I have encountered an error with @NgModule() in my project. Despite attempting to resolve the issue by removing and reinstalling the node_modules folder, the problem persists. Could you please help me find a solution?"

[image]

Comment: Did you import all the red Modules ? : BrowserModule, CompanyModule, DashboardMoudle ...

Comment: Yes, I already added